# every slide a different time

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow

I am making a slider that displays a background and a text, but i want every slide to have a different time duration. I don't know how to make this

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="black_background">
        <div id="typewriter"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="black_background">
        <div>
            <p class="yellow">Wij</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="black_background">
        <div>
            <p class="yellow">Zijn</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
        $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

        setInterval(function() {
            $('#slideshow > div:first')
                .fadeOut(1)
                .next()
                .fadeIn(1)
                .end()
                .appendTo('#slideshow');
        }, 1500,);
    </script>
```

Comment: you could set the duration of `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` to make them slow or fast. Checkout the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

Comment: That is not what i mean, i want every slide duration different.

Comment: Try [Math.Random()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) to generate randomness for duration if that's what you wish.

Comment: I want the first slide to be 2 seconds and the second slide 1 second and third slide to be 3 seconds. Not randomized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution for you:

```js
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

// Function for changing to the next slide
let nextSlide = (count, delay) => {
  // Set the delay on the slide
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Hide the current slide
    $('#slideshow > div:nth-of-type(' + count + ')').hide();
    // If we've reached the end of the slides, set count back to 1,
    // otherwise, increment by 1
    (count !== $('#slideshow > div').length) ? count++ : count = 1;
    // Show the next slide
    $('#slideshow > div:nth-of-type(' + count + ')').show();
    // Set the delay to the value of the data-delay attribute on the
    // slide elements
    delay = $('#slideshow > div:nth-of-type(' + count + ')').data('delay');
    // Call this function recursively
    nextSlide(count, delay);
  }, delay);
}

nextSlide(1, $('#slideshow > div:first').data('delay'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
  <div data-delay="2000" class="black_background">
    <div id="typewriter">First</div>
  </div>
  <div data-delay="1000" class="black_background">
    <div>
      <p class="yellow">Wij</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-delay="3000" class="black_background">
    <div>
      <p class="yellow">Zijn</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice the `data-delay` attributes on your slide elements, which requires a number in milliseconds, for how long you want each slide to last.